# Выполнение функции после определенного времени

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем добрый вечер! Столкнулся с проблемой, никак не получается задать **setTimeout** для функции таймера обратного отсчета.

То есть суть такова: как только первый таймер заканчивает свою работу (по истечении 60 секунд), то запущен должен быть второй таймер (для него получается задержка 120 сек), для третьего задержка получается 180 секунд.

Как правильно задать данный параметр? Спасибо заранее. 
Код первого таймера и второго (обратный отсчет):

```
        var countdown =  $("#countdown").countdown360({
        radius      : 20,
        seconds     : 60,
        fontColor   : '#ffffff',
        autostart   : false,
        onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
       });
        countdown.start();
        console.log('countdown360 ',countdown);
        $(document).on("click","button",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
            if(type === "time-remaining")
            {
                var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

            }
            else
            {
                var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

            }
        });

        var countdown =  $("#countdown2").countdown360({
        radius      : 20,
        seconds     : 60,
        fontColor   : '#ffffff',

        autostart   : false,
        onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
       });
        countdown.start();
        console.log('countdown360 ',countdown);
        $(document).on("click","button",function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var type = $(this).attr("data-type");
            if(type === "time-remaining")
            {
                var timeRemaining = countdown.getTimeRemaining();

            }
            else
            {
                var timeElapsed = countdown.getElapsedTime();

            }
        });
```

Comment: что-то совсем не понятная функция. Вы пробовали использовать встроенные таймеры в jquery?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да, но видимо руки кривые, по этому и обратился за помощью. прикладываю скрин для понятности ситуации что требуется реализовать. https://ibb.co/dHZF0Q

Comment: @Horchynskyi а так же ссылку: https://cvingcam.000webhostapp.com/CVINGWeb/index.html

Comment: там все идут 60. вам надо 3 по разнице в 60 секунду?

Comment: @Horchynskyi да, получается у каждого таймера задержка должна быть вдвое больше предыдущего.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В плане красивостей 0, но таймер работает)

```js
$(function(){
            function setTimerToElement(element, maxCount){
                let seconds = 0,
                    timer = setInterval(function(){
                    $(element).text(++seconds);
                    $(element).next().css({'height': seconds/2+'px'});
                    if(seconds == 60) {
                        clearInterval(timer);
                        if(counter < maxCount) setTimerToElement($('#count-text-'+ ++counter), 3);
                    };
                }, 1000);
            };
            let counter = 1;
            setTimerToElement($('#count-text-'+counter), 3);
        });
```

```css
.timer{
    display: flex;
}
.timer-decoration{
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: cornflowerblue; 
}
.timer-background{
    width: 5px;
    height: 0px;
    background-color: blue; 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><div class="timer">What can you tell me about yourself?<div id="count-text-1" class="timer-decoration">0</div><div class="timer-background"></div></div></div>
    <div><div class="timer">Can you list your strengths?<div id="count-text-2" class="timer-decoration">0</div><div class="timer-background"></div></div></div>
    <div><div class="timer">What weaknesses do you have?<div id="count-text-3" class="timer-decoration">0</div><div class="timer-background"></div></div></div>
```